# How to use opendolphin without http sticky sessions in a load balanced scenario?

Tags: opendolphin, canoo, dolphin-platform

I read "Those who would like to enjoy the binding, presentation model structuring, testing capabilities, toolkit independence, and all the other benefits of OpenDolphin, but prefer REST (or other) remoting for data access, can use OpenDolphin with the in-memory configuration"

But I could not find any further hints in the docs?

I can't rely on sticky sessions in my load balanced webserver.
Therefore I need to plugin something different for the http session state.

Is there a opendolphin config property prepared for this? If not are there any plugin points available?

Answer (score 0):

since OpenDolphin and Dolphin Platform use the remote presentation model pattern to synchronize presentation models between client and server you need a state on the server. Currently this state is defined in the session. As you said it's no problem to use load balancing with sticky sessions to provide several server instances. If you need dynamic updates between the clients a distributed event bus like hazelcast will help.

> Therefore I need to plugin something different for the http session
>   state.

What do you need? With the last version (0.8.6) of [Dolphin Platform](https://github.com/canoo/dolphin-platform) you can access the http client in the client API and provide custom headers or cookies. Will this help? Can you please tell us what you need or open an issue at the [Dolphin Platform github repo](https://github.com/canoo/dolphin-platform)?